# 1oz copper ok for card edge connector in prototype?

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-fabrication

I'm doing a small prototype system and would like to fab boards at one of the inexpensive Chinese places like:

https://www.elecrow.com/pcb-manufacturing.html

I'm going to bus the boards using ribbon-cable card-edge connectors like:

http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/22003O/3mtm-100-in-card-edge-connector-drilled-flngs-ts0012.pdf

... with gold wiping area.

I'm wondering if this will work ok (issues such as poor conductivity initially, failure after a few connect/disconnect cycles, etc).

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use headers on the boards instead ?   It'd be a trade-off of increased parts cost versus increased board cost of gold-plating the card edge lands.

Comment: Depending on the smoothness of the chamfer edge on the traces that interface with the connector, the number of connecter cycles before erosion occurs may vary widely

Comment: This type of connection is all the time with no problems. The copper weight isn't going to make much difference, its is nickel and gold plating that matter.

Comment: @Tony Stewart You're talking about the edge of the board where it inserts into the 3M connector ?  The linked datasheet shows the way they want it shaped.   But of course the budget PCB house probably can't do this.   I was figuring maybe I'd just chamfer it myself.   Maybe I'll be better off abandoning the card-edge scheme and using headers.